# Is SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL a valid Android camera type?

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-camera, surfaceholder

I am building an augmented reality app that takes frames from the camera, filters them using a few image processing techniques, and displays them to the user in place of the camera preview.

When I first started I was simply calling:

```
holder = getHolder();
holder.addCallback(this);
... 
camera.addCallbackBuffer(buffer);
camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(callback);
camera.startPreview();
```

Inside the callback I do the following:

```
SurfaceHolder holder;
Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
if (c != null) {
    try {
        // Draw to canvas
    } finally {
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }
}
```

This worked fairly well, and was giving decent performance on the Motorola Photon.

I also own a Motorola Droid as well as an LG Optimus; on these two devices **onPreviewFrame** would never get called, and as a result the holder would never get drawn in the callback.  And the user would be stuck with a black screen.

After searching around I found that the following line needed to be added

```
holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

With this line I finally get the callback.  But the problem is if I try to call `holder.lockCanvas()` I get an error since this isn't allowed with `SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS`.

Now I've been able to work around this by placing an `ImageView` on top of the `SurfaceView` and drawing the frames to the `ImageView` instead.  But the performance of this is terrible in comparison to using `SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL`.

**My questions are:**

- Is `SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL` a valid usable type, or can I only trust `SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS`?
- If so, is it possible to determine if a device supports `SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL` so I can squeeze that extra bit of performance out of devices that do?  Are there certain Android versions, or manufacturers that support it?

As a side note, I understand that for Honeycomb (3.0) these values are no longer supported.  But they are requred for 2.3 and lower.  Also for ICS (4.0), the new `SurfaceTexture` pipeline is blazing fast.  But I would still like to support at least 2.2 and 2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I have not received an official answer, and probably will not since on newer Android versions this is deprecated, I have found that SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL is not valid for use with a camera preview on many devices.

This answer comes from testing on various devices.  On some devices no video will ever be received; it has nothing to do with the various parameters used.